# How can I order this query?

Tags: sql-server

[DEMO SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca11a/14)

I have the query like in the demo above, but I don´t know how to order this query, I want the result to be something like this:

```
 Name
-----
Menu_1
-------
..... Sub_Menu_1
-------
Menu_2
-------
..... Sub_Menu_2
-------
..........Sub_Sub_Menu_2
-------
Menu_3
-------
```

How can I do this? thanks

***Edit*** (info from the SQLFiddle demo)

**The table:**

```
CREATE TABLE Menus 
    (
     IdMenu int  primary key, 
     IdParentMenu varchar(20), 
     Name varchar(30)
    );
```

**The data:**

```
INSERT INTO Menus
(IdMenu, IdParentMenu, Name)
VALUES
('1', '0', 'Menu_1'),
('2', '0', 'Menu_2'),
('3', '0', 'Menu_3'),
('4', '1', 'SubMenu_1'),
('5', '2', 'SubMenu_2'),
('6', '5', 'Sub-SubMenu_2');
```

**My query:**

```
WITH MenuCTE (IdMenu, IdParentMenu, ParentMenu, Name, Lvl)
AS
(
    -- Anchor member
    SELECT m.IdMenu, m.IdParentMenu, CAST('' AS varchar) AS ParentMenu, m.Name, 0 AS Lvl
    FROM dbo.Menus AS m
    WHERE CAST(m.IdParentMenu AS INT) = 0
    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member
    SELECT m.IdMenu, m.IdParentMenu, CAST(mc.Name AS varchar) AS ParentMenu, m.Name, Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
    FROM dbo.Menus AS m
    INNER JOIN MenuCTE AS mc
        ON CAST(m.IdParentMenu AS INT) = mc.IdMenu
)
SELECT IdMenu, IdParentMenu, ParentMenu, REPLICATE('....', Lvl) + Name
FROM MenuCTE
--WHERE Lvl > 0
ORDER BY IdParentMenu
GO
```

Comment: Next time please include the (related) info from the demo (or from any external links), this allows the further readers to understand the question or answer when the remote data is unavailable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a field that calculates path and order by this field:

```
WITH MenuCTE (IdMenu, IdParentMenu, ParentMenu, Path, Name, Lvl)
AS
(
    -- Anchor member
    SELECT m.IdMenu, m.IdParentMenu, 
           CAST('' AS varchar) AS ParentMenu, 
           CAST(m.Name AS varchar) AS Path, 
           m.Name AS Name, 
           0 AS Lvl
    FROM dbo.Menus AS m
    WHERE CAST(m.IdParentMenu AS INT) = 0
    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member
    SELECT m.IdMenu, m.IdParentMenu, 
           CAST(mc.Name AS varchar) AS ParentMenu, 
           CAST(mc.Path + '.'+ m.Name AS varchar) AS Path,
           m.Name, 
           Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
    FROM dbo.Menus AS m
    INNER JOIN MenuCTE AS mc
        ON CAST(m.IdParentMenu AS INT) = mc.IdMenu
)
SELECT IdMenu, IdParentMenu, ParentMenu, 
       REPLICATE('....', Lvl) + Name, Path
FROM MenuCTE
ORDER BY Path
```

Note: In the above query `Path` is built using `Name` field, hence ordering of menus, submenus, etc. is performed on basis of their names. `Path` values are like:

```
Menu_1
Menu_1.SubMenu_1
Menu_2
Menu_2.SubMenu_2
Menu_2.SubMenu_2.Sub-SubMenu_2
```

If you want to order by ids, then simply built `Path` using `IdMenu` in place of `Name`. In this case `Path` values are going to be like:

```
1
1.4
2
2.5
2.5.6
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca11a/17)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, It´s helped me so much ;-D

Answer (score 1):

This should be good.

```
WITH MenuCTE (IdMenu, IdParentMenu, ParentMenu, Ord, Name, Lvl)
AS
(
    -- Anchor member
    SELECT m.IdMenu, m.IdParentMenu, CAST('' AS varchar) AS ParentMenu, CAST(m.IdMenu AS varchar) as Ord, m.Name, 0 AS Lvl
    FROM dbo.Menus AS m
    WHERE CAST(m.IdParentMenu AS INT) = 0
    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member
    SELECT m.IdMenu, m.IdParentMenu, CAST(mc.Name AS varchar) AS ParentMenu, cast((mc.Ord + CAST(m.IdMenu AS varchar)) as varchar) as Ord, m.Name, Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
    FROM dbo.Menus AS m
    INNER JOIN MenuCTE AS mc
        ON CAST(m.IdParentMenu AS INT) = mc.IdMenu
)
SELECT ord, IdMenu, IdParentMenu, ParentMenu, REPLICATE('....', Lvl) + Name
FROM MenuCTE
--WHERE Lvl > 0
ORDER BY ord
GO
```